# Scaling text using CSS

Tags: css

What is and is there a way scale text using CSS based on the amount of text within a DIV.

I've this page I've created at http://www.directiongroup.com/tweethearts/ and the CSS for the text is (with a fixed size of 32px):

.jta-tweet-text

```
{
    color: #ed1c24;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What should the relation of the text to the div be? For example, do you want 5 lines of text in a 400px high div, no matter the amount of text? Or is it one line of text and you want it to fill the div, wrapping where necessary?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with CSS alone but you could do it with a bit of JavaScript.

Counting the number of characters in the text and setting the CSS `font-size` property as required.

Here's a quick example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/pjByL/

```
$('.heart').each(function(){
var textLength = $(this).text().length
    if(textLength > 26)
    {
       $(this).css('font-size', '10px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve that with `css` you have to use `java scrip`t for this check this may that's help you

### http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but still showing up top in search results, so I'll post a modern answer.

If you spec your font-size in viewport (vw) units in your CSS, the font is automatically scaled without the use of javascript

CSS

```
font-size: 23vw;
```

For the detailed specification and other options, read the W3.org spec [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#future).

Comment: I don't see how setting the size based on the window width will cause the size to scale based on the amount of text

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** as answered by 'couzzi'

[css for double height text and double width text in font style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408926/css-for-double-height-text-and-double-width-text-in-font-style)

Fiddle that includes all vendor prefixes for transform and transform-origin:http://jsfiddle.net/LTaAy/1/

**HTML**

```
  <p class="doubleWidth">DOUBLE WIDTH</p>
  <p class="doubleHeight">Double Height</p>
  <p class="doubleWidthandHeight">Double Width and Height</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
p.doubleWidth {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2);
}
p.doubleHeight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(2);
}
p.doubleWidthandHeight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(2);
}
```

Comment: Muhammad, if you're going to copy and paste my answer ver batim, all I ask is that you not make it seem like you've come up with the answer yourself. Thank you.

Comment: I absolutely didn't, I was not planning to add the code, but since there is a fiddle link there must be a code in the answer, otherwise SO won't allow my post. 
I added the link to you answer in mine.