# css for double height text and double width text in font style

Tags: css, html, printing, fonts, typography

Any one can help me to do double height text and double width text in font style(as like in dot matrix printers) in css without using any images.

Any code other than this?

```
heading{
   font-weight:bold; 
   width:200%;
}
```

What I expect is  as below.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: an answer has a comment : you cannot achieve this completely in CSS. Else : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226069/scaling-text-using-css

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OP,

Updated fiddle that includes all vendor prefixes for `transform` and `transform-origin`:http://jsfiddle.net/LTaAy/1/

<strike>See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTaAy/</strike>

### IMG

[image: Fiddle Screenshot]

### HTML

```
  <p class="doubleWidth">DOUBLE WIDTH</p>
  <p class="doubleHeight">Double Height</p>
  <p class="doubleWidthandHeight">Double Width and Height</p>
```

### CSS

```
p {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
p.doubleWidth {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2);
}
p.doubleHeight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(2);
}
p.doubleWidthandHeight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(2);
}
```

<strike>I only included 2 vendors prefixes, but they should be applied as necessary.</strike> 
 - Only true above, This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LTaAy/1/ has been updated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: CAUTION: transformations in css do not actually affect the space layout (the flow) of elements on a page, they only affect the visual form of the transformed element. So what that means is, using transformations to do this could [**in some cases cause overlaps with other content**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTaAy/9/). Appropriate measures of padding, margins, widths, heights, or what not would need to be taken to help overcome that in cases where it is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

### **CSS transform:scale**

Check out transform scale, that should do the trick:

http://www.css3files.com/transform/

```
-webkit-transform:scale(2,1);
-moz-transform:scale(2,1);
-ms-transform:scale(2,1);
-o-transform:scale(2,1);
transform:scale(2,1);
```

[letteringjs.com](http://letteringjs.com) can be used to apply this CSS to each letter independently through automatic span injection as you might have an issue with layout if the whole span is text span is stretched.

Additionally, you might be able to get away with `width: 50%;` on your double width text to restrain it within your layout.

### **Create your own font**

Otherwise edit the font yourself. Use a tool like [Font Creator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html). Just manipulate the scale, and save 2 new fonts, one with 200% width, and one with 200% height. Throw them into [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and reference all 3 as unique `@font-face` font-families.

[image: Font Creator - Manipulating Fonts]

Comment: i want to increase in font only not whole div or image

Comment: Anything wrong with applying it to a span around the text in question?

Comment: Not bad, but you should specify unprefixed property on the last place. And [do not refer to W3Schools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: i am expecting more answers please

Comment: In combination with http://letteringjs.com/ you can probably apply this to each letter so you reduce layout issues...

Comment: thanks for your interest patrick, but i need css only by using any font

Comment: `transform:scale` is it. Either apply it to the whole thing of text, or, put spans or some form of tag around each individual letter and apply the CSS to that. letteringjs.com will do this span injection for you.