# How to put double width and double height characters in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane

I'm using a `JTextPane` to display a kind of bus ticket that uses a monospaced font. I am using `StyleConstants` and `SimpleAttributeSet`to set bold and italic text, but I would like to also use double width and height characters. I don't want to make a double-sized font, by double I mean that a character 'A' which I want to be double-width, would get stretched in width, but not in height, and vice versa for double-height, like in this image I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408926/css-for-double-height-text-and-double-width-text-in-font-style).

I really don't know any method to do so and googling didn't give me an answer. Maybe a way to adjust the size of a font horizontally and vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust the size of a font to double width:

```
// Input: an existing Font object called 'font'.
final int style = Font.PLAIN;
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.setToScale(2.0, 1.0);
Font doubleWidthFont = font.deriveFont(style, transform);
```

I haven't tried this code, so please let me know if it doesn't work exactly as written.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: (1+) Nice solution. Didn't realize you could scale a Font. I've always scaled the Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's for JEditorPane, but also should work with JTextPane
http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

Comment: That code just measures the height of the text, as I understand it.