# Android: How to make double width and double height text in webview content

Tags: android, text, webview, size

I want to show some content on Android webview which is related to receipt printing content
I want to show 2x width (or double width) and 2x height (or double height) text for few lines
Can someone help?
See example image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik you can only set up font size (through `WebSettings` class)... `WebView` isn't so elastic and doesn't provide such detailed options for managing/styling printed text. for this purposes CSS is made for. eventually it would be better to implement this feature in Javascript on web-side or downloading data as clear text, modify proper lines (adding CSS) and use `loadData(...)` method of `WebView`

Comment: I tried using CSS style sheet in webview but it does not have any effect

Comment: I assure you that CSS works well in `WebView`, is loaded, is respected, is drawn. you've probably misconfigured your setup, maybe wrong path to CSS file

Comment: I am not getting such property in CSS which works for android webview. can you give me example CSS for double width and double height?

Comment: sime example, with same sample image, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408926/css-for-double-height-text-and-double-width-text-in-font-style), preview live [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/LTaAy/1/)

Comment: consider upvoting mine and linked answers if helpful, good luck! :)